# Fibonacci's Sequence using forloop

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

I'm trying to create an array with length `n` (user input), and I thought that I could use the associated `i` values within the array to calculate my fibonacci sum.

Here is what I have so far, and I can't figure out how I should be extracting the `i` value as an int to be able to calculate the sum.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please enter a value for n: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
    
        int[] newArray = new int[n];
    
        int f1 = newArray[0];
        int f2 = newArray[1];
        
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(f1 + " ");
            int sum = f1 + f2;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to approach this and can explain a bit of the theory that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence has to start with some nonzero value. Otherwise you're just adding up zeroes.

Comment: Please think about your request. You want that we write down something for you ... that was written down many many times before. There are plenty of sites out there that discuss the Fibonacci sequence in all detail ... for beginners, but also for experts. Many of these sites come with full implementations, in various languages. So: why do you think it is necessary to write ... the zillionth question about Fib here, to explain things again ... for you? My point is: you learn programming by programming, and by searching for documentation. All day long. Asking others for explanations ...

Comment: should be your *last* choice. And then it should be a specific question, not like "here my code, now what".

Comment: And note: dropping your question, to then walk away, and only return hours or days later is also not appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an array to store the Fibonacci sequence, you should access the Fibonacci numbers using index in this array and there is no need to use intermediate variables `f1, f2, sum`.

```java
int[] fiboNums = new int[n]; // assuming n >= 2
    
fiboNums[0] = 1;
fiboNums[1] = 1;

System.out.printf("f(%2d)=%,13d  ", i, fiboNums[i]);        
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    fiboNums[i] = fiboNums[i - 1] + fiboNums[i - 2];

    System.out.printf("f(%2d)=%,13d  ", i, fiboNums[i]);
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

However, using `int` to represent Fibonacci number may not be a good idea because this sequence grows exponentially and integer overflow occurs when `i == 46`.

```
f( 1)=            1  f( 2)=            2  f( 3)=            3  f( 4)=            5  f( 5)=            8  
f( 6)=           13  f( 7)=           21  f( 8)=           34  f( 9)=           55  f(10)=           89  
f(11)=          144  f(12)=          233  f(13)=          377  f(14)=          610  f(15)=          987  
f(16)=        1,597  f(17)=        2,584  f(18)=        4,181  f(19)=        6,765  f(20)=       10,946  
f(21)=       17,711  f(22)=       28,657  f(23)=       46,368  f(24)=       75,025  f(25)=      121,393  
f(26)=      196,418  f(27)=      317,811  f(28)=      514,229  f(29)=      832,040  f(30)=    1,346,269  
f(31)=    2,178,309  f(32)=    3,524,578  f(33)=    5,702,887  f(34)=    9,227,465  f(35)=   14,930,352  
f(36)=   24,157,817  f(37)=   39,088,169  f(38)=   63,245,986  f(39)=  102,334,155  f(40)=  165,580,141  
f(41)=  267,914,296  f(42)=  433,494,437  f(43)=  701,408,733  f(44)=1,134,903,170  f(45)=1,836,311,903
```

Similarly, using `long` would allow to fit only 91 Fibonacci numbers.